# XSLT: transform XML with a lot (>150) attributes named value1, value2, ... with grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, muenchian-grouping

i'm new to xsl and have the following problem:

There's a XML like

```
<data>
<row FilterValue1="1" Value2="2" FilterValue3="3" />
<row FilterValue1="a" Value2="b" FilterValue3="c" />
</data>

<features>
<row title="Feature 1" provideFilter="yes" />
<row title="Feature 2" provideFilter="no"/>
<row title="Feature 3" provideFilter="yes">
</features>
```

Depending on 'provideFilter', i want to create a Dropdown list like

```
<label for="Value1">Feature 1</label>
<select id="Value1">
<option>1</option>
<option>a</option>
</select>

<label for="Value3">Feature 3</label>
<select id="Value3">
<option>3</option>
<option>c</option>
</select>
```

I can't change the main structure, but the 'data' part is already a combination of two XML files which I created, so what is changeable is the name 'FilterValue' or 'Value'.

Until now, i tried the following (using xsl 1.0):

```
<xsl:template match="features">
 <xsl:for-each select="row">
  <label>
   <xsl:attribute name="for">Value<xsl:value-of select="position()" /></xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="@title">
  </label>
  <xsl:call-template name="featureOptions">
   <xsl:with-param name="featureNr" select="position()" />
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="featureOptions">
 <xsl:param name="featureNr" />
 <xsl:variable name="FilterValue">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('FilterValue', $featureNr)" />
 </xsl:variable>
 <select>
  <xsl:attribute name="id">Value<xsl:value-of select="$featureNr" /></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:for-each select="//data/row">
   <xsl:if test="@*[contains(name(), $FilterValue)] != '' and not(preceding-sibling::z:row[@*[contains(name(), $FilterValue)] = current()/@*[contains(name(), $FilterValue)]])">       
    <option>
     <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="@*[contains(name(), $FilterWert)]" /></xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:value-of select="@*[contains(name(), $FilterValue)]" />
    </option>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </select>
</xsl:template>
```

So, this solution only works for less than 10 FilterValues. This is why I tried to change the condition `contains(name(), $FilterValue)` into `$FilterValue = substring(name(), string-length(name())-string-length($FilterValue) + 1)`, but this was not working (didn't see anything in my browser). When I tested my new condition i once deleted the `preceding::sibling ..` condition which i used to check for distinct values, then the dropdown box was shown (but of course there were no distinct options...). I did go on with reading about keys and grouping, but since i will have about 300 FilterValue-Attributes i don't understand how to use keys without making 300 of them, while the provideFilter-Option is not fixed? So next thing i read about was the generate-id()-Function. Same problem as before: how to combine it with the condition `$FilterWert = substring(name(), string-length(name())-string-length($FilterWert) + 1)` (which is looking for the "right" attributes)? My ideas were something like

```
<xsl:key name="rows" match="z:row" use="."></xsl:key>

.....

<xsl:for-each select="//data/row[generate-id() = generate-id(key(rows, .)/@*[$FilterValue = substring(name(), string-length(name())-string-length($FilterValue) + 1)][1])]">
<option>
   <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />              
</option>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or another `for-each` in the featureOptions-Template

```
<xsl:for-each select="//data/row[generate-id() = generate-id(preceding-sibling::row/@*[$FilterValue = substring(name(), string-length(name())-string-length($FilterValue) + 1)])]">
```

None of them showed the correct Dropdown Box. Please could someone explain me why both ideas don't work and give me a new idea or solution?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thank you!